How to perform one to many mapping relationship in MERN
I want to establish a relationship between the user and notes with one to many mapping relationship. But most probably i was getting error only. I don't know about the populate in mongoose in expressJS. Can someone help me to sort out the problem by explaining the populate() in mongoose express.
User Model
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")

const joi = require('joi')
const passwordComplexity = require('joi-password-complexity')

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,    
        required: true
    },
    notes: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'noteModel' }]
})

userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function(){
    const token = jwt.sign({_id:this._id}, process.env.JWTPRIVATEKEY,{expiresIn:'7d'})
    return token;
}

const validate =(data)=>{
    const schema = joi.object({
        email: joi.string().required().label("Email"),
        password: passwordComplexity().required().label("Password")
    });
    return schema.validate(data);
}

const User = mongoose.model("user", userSchema)

module.exports = {User,validate} 

Note Model
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const notesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        heading:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        note:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        created_at:{
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        },
        user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
    }
)

const noteModel = mongoose.model("note" , notesSchema)

module.exports = noteModel

notes.js in the route folder
const router = require('express').Router();

const noteModel = require('../model/note');

router.get("/getNotes", async(req,res)=>{
    noteModel.find({})
    .then(note=>res.json(note))
    .catch(err=>res.json(err))
})

router.post("/createNotes" , async(req,res)=>{
    noteModel.create(req.body)
    .then(note=>res.json(note))
    .catch(err=>res.json(err))
})

router.get("/getNote/:id" , async(req,res)=>{
    const id = req.params.id;
    noteModel.findById(id)
    .then(note=>res.json(note))
    .catch(err=>res.json(err))
})

router.put("/updateNote/:id" , async(req,res)=>{
    const id = req.params.id;
    noteModel.findByIdAndUpdate(id,req.body)
    .then(note=>res.json(note))
    .catch(err=>res.json(err))
})

router.delete("/deleteNote/:id" , async(req,res)=>{
    const id = req.params.id;
    noteModel.findByIdAndDelete(id,req.body)
    .then(note=>res.json(note))
    .catch(err=>res.json(err))
})

module.exports = router

